# how to setup openvpn services on servers behind firewall

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openvpn

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server behind our department firewall, I could SSH login via `domain name` and port `8022`, I tried setup openvpn services following guide: [the Ubuntu 12.04 Server guide -- OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/C/openvpn.html). While my problem is that I only have port `8022` opened for SSH access, I don't have 1194 for openvpn connection, is there a way to make the openvpn services be connected by Windows7 client?

Thanks for any suggestion.

(by the way, I tried [OpenVPN over SSH tunneling (PDF link)](http://www.anonyproz.com/openvpnsshtunnel.pdf) searched from this forum, but couldn't make it work for me.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use official OpenVPN client software to connect? If yes, you can specify the port in the client configuration file (client.ovpn in Windows) with this line: port 8022

Comment: thanks for reply. I did use official client in windows. So this require openvpn server to be ran at port 8022 instead of 1194 I guess? And I would lost access to SSH then? thanks again!

Comment: The ports used by server can be configured in OpenVPN server configuration file. Client and server should use same ports. And of course there should be no firewall blockage between them.